# Optimise Django query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model in my Django project:

```
class AmazonSearchFrequency(models.Model):
    keyword_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    frequency = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

I am storing around 2 million rows of data in this table but whenever I do a search query like

```
AmazonSearchFrequency.objects.filter(keyword_name=keyword)
```

it takes a long time to execute the query.

Is there any way in Django to optimize this query?

Comment: Have you [indexed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.indexes) that column? Adding an index will significantly speed up filtering on that column

Comment: Yes as said by @dirkgroten use Indexing and caching. it will improve performance and you may use `values()`  to get the columns only that you use.

Comment: I found this article a very good summary of Django ORM optimization - https://medium.com/@hansonkd/performance-problems-in-the-django-orm-1f62b3d04785

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always [index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.indexes) columns that you will use in filters later on. This is how databases can significantly speed up searches. Without an index, the db has to go through every single row!

In you case, this would look like this:

```
class AmazonSearchFrequency(models.Model):
    keyword_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    frequency = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['keyword_name'], name='keyword_name_idx'),
        ]
```

Don't forget to make migrations and migrate after adding an index.

Note: primary keys, foreign keys and fields set as `unique` or `unique_together` are indexed by default, you don't need to add those.